# How many stars do you need to get all the badges?

Tags: super-mario-maker

Ok so I have been playing [Super Mario Maker](http://supermariomaker.nintendo.com/) for a long time now (almost 2 years) and I have only gotten about 14 stars (at the time of this question). I think i have only gotten 1 badge (again at the time of this question), so i just want to know how many stars it takes to get all the badges. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii-u/805618-super-mario-maker/cheats), here are the different medals and the number of stars required to get them :

```
Unlockable                              How to unlock
Goomba medal                            Receive one star
Koopa Troopa medal - 20 stage cap       Receive 50 stars
Piranha Plant medal - 30 stage cap      Receive 150 stars
Spiny medal - 40 stage cap              Receive 300 stars
Cheep Cheep medal - 50 stage cap        Receive 500 stars
Blooper medal - 60 stage cap            Receive 800 stars
Lakitu medal - 70 stage cap             Receive 1300 stars
Bowser medal - 80 stage cap             Receive 2000 stars
Toad medal - 90 stage cap               Receive 3000 stars
Princess Peach medal - 100 stage cap    Receive 5000 stars
```

So you would need 5000 stars to get all of the medals.